# honda activa power start problem

Tags: honda, starting, activa

When I try to start the activa by power start, a sound like trik trik is coming from the front cover. Upon opening the cover, the two black switches are making the sound. What is the problem?
Or is the battery the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine it's the starter.

BUT, I would start by checking the battery. You can try jumping it from a same voltage battery, or take it to an Auto Parts store. Batteries are the most common cause of starting problems.

I'm guessing the clicking is the relays, which would indicate most of your electronics are good. Therefore, it's probably your starter not working. Again, most autoparts stores will test it for you, even with it still on the bike.

Comment: But my battery voltage is 12.6 volt

Comment: If the battery voltage is good. The problem probably is the starter. You can check youtube for how to test the starter. Or you can take it to a part shop.